# Create external permission and add to wso2 Role by API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need create a new external permission by code or wso2 internal api, and add it to wso2 existing Role, it is possible? how?
I can add a new external Role, but only can add existing permissions.
I'm ussing Identity Server 5.5.0

I need this... but by code or api.
[Example: create new permission to Service Provider by UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLlQ9.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **RemoteUserStoreManagerService** to achieve this. Refer official wos2 documentation on [Managing Users and Roles with APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs)